# Entity Framework deep select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am running into following error:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parametername: path
```

With the following code:

```
return _context.Section.Include(x => x.Leagues.Select(y => y.Games.Where(v=>v.GameStart > DateTime.Now))).ToList();
```

I am trying to select all sections with all leagues that have active games.
I just cannot get around this error and have not managed to find a proper solution on SF.

Thankful for any help

Regards, Marianne

Comment: I think this is what you want. `return _context.Section.Where(x => x.Leagues.Any(y => y.Games.Any(v => v.GameStart > DateTime.Now))).ToList();` the `Include` is for eager loading. The `Select` is to express what you want to return and not how to filter it which is what `Where` is for. `Where` expects boolean expressions which is where `Any` comes in to play.

Comment: `Include` is not for filtering. It implements so called "eager loading" ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)). To filter the result, use a normal `Where` outside the `Include`.

Comment: Hello Igor. Almost. I need ALL sections. I need the leagues with active games. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: @MarianneMarkwardt - updated the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, if not you need to provide the complete data model as it relates to this question.

```
return _context.Section
  .Select(x => new{Section = x, Leagues = x.Leagues.Where(y => y.Games.Any(v => v.GameStart > DateTime.Now))})
  .ToList();
```

- `Include` is for eager loading.
- `Select` is to express what you want to return and not how to filter it, very similar to T-Sql
- `Where` is for filtering but it expects `boolean` expressions.
- `Any` will evaluate the inner expression and return `true` if any records are evaluated as `true`.

Side note - keep in mind that `DateTime.Now` also uses the time in your evaluation expression.